# Getting "failed to resolve broker hostname" when trying to connect to rabbitmq in another docker container

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, amqp, nameko

I've been searching for hours as to how to connected to an external docker container running RabbitMQ.

I'm trying to run a few services using Nameko which requires RabbitMQ. I've started my RabbitMQ container using the following command:

```
docker run -d -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 --hostname my-rabbit --name rabbit-container rabbitmq:3-management
```

I've created a yaml config file called config.yaml with this inside:

```
AMQP_URI: 'pyamqp://guest:guest@my-rabbit:5672'
```

I start my rabbit container and my Nameko container and run the following command in the Nameko container's CLI:

```
nameko shell --config config.yaml
```

I get a the following error:

```
OSError: failed to resolve broker hostname
```

Docker, RabbitMQ, and Nameko are all new technologies to me, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Please let me know if you see anything that sticks out.

Answer (score 2):

I start my rabbit with docker-compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  rabbit:
    container_name: rabbitmq
    image: rabbitmq:3.7-management
    ports:
        - "5672:5672"
        - "15672:15672" # Exposing RabbitMQ web management on different port for convenience
    restart: always
```

and config.yaml:

```
AMQP_URI: amqp://guest:guest@$localhost:5672/
```